# Android swiperefreshlayout + framelayout

Tags: android

I have the following problem: I have long `ListView`, but when I scroll back up the onRefresh is triggered instead of scrolling back to the top first. How can I fix this?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/splash_background">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MyActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"></FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I am inserting the following fragment into the `FrameLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/splash_background">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/files_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: cant understand what you are asking?

Comment: you probably need to subclass `SwipeRefreshLayout` and override `canChildScrollup`

Comment: @Panther i have scrollview, i scroll down, after it i want to scroll up, but i can't because swipetorefreshlayout called method refresh

Comment: @Panther i add full layouts

Comment: scroll view is missing :-/

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer for using SwipeRefreshLayout + NestedScrollView + RecyclerView, as I think it's the use case that many people may want to implement.

Situation:
You want to have multiple views inside a SwipeRefreshLayout (maybe you hide and show some depending on the state). These views need to be able to scroll, so you need to use some kind of a ScrollView. You also have a RecyclerView, which doesn't really need a ScrollView. Putting a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView (or NestedScrollView) can be bad for performance and functionality, as all the items in the RecyclerView will be created immediately (onBindViewHolder() etc). So you need them separate, therefore you put them in a FrameLayout next to each other. It looks like this:

Simplified layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:fillViewport="true">

            <include layout="@layout/empty_view" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView />

        <include layout="@layout/progress_bar"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Problem:

Unfortunately, SwipeRefreshLayout normally expects a single RecyclerView child, and it doesn't work right otherwise. When you've scrolled anywhere in the list and you try to scroll back up, a refresh is triggered. Normally it should be triggered when you reach the top.

Solution:

```
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnChildScrollUpCallback(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnChildScrollUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean canChildScrollUp(@NonNull SwipeRefreshLayout parent,
                                        @Nullable View child) {
            return recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1);
        }
    });
```

It's a very simple solution that doesn't seem to be well-known. The swipeRefreshLayout will check whether its child can scroll up, and we inform it by simply checking whether the recyclerView can scroll up. The callback canChildScrollUp() is called multiple times during a gesture, but it's a low enough number not to be a performance concern.

There might be a better way to establish the connection between the two, but I'm not aware of it. If you find it let me know :-)

Note that this is a simplified solution and it may not work that well if you have multiple visible views, apart from the recyclerView (I guess you should be able to pull and refresh in case you drag on top of another view, while the recyclerView is scrolled somewhere down. But this solution does not account for such cases).

The "child" is always the FrameLayout in this example. Since we have a more complex layout than just one RecyclerView, we need to handle this ourselves. This would work best if we call canScrollVertically() on the view where the gesture is taking place.  In my example I am always calling it on my RecyclerView, because this fulfills my current requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking for this solution for some time now. It's 2020 and the problem is still there. In my case, I had to use a `FrameLayout` with `ListView` and `TextView` in order to call `listView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty))`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't remember where i found this solution, but I believe there is an issue with the SwipeRefreshLayout in some circumstances when scrolling back upwards. The workaround I have applied is to add an onScrollListener to the listview which enables and disabled swipe refresh whenever the list isn't in the top position. A sample of this is the following:

```
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {}

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            int topRowVerticalPosition =
                    (absListView == null || absListView.getChildCount() == 0) ?
                            0 : absListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 ? absListView.getChildAt(0).getTop() : -1;
            swipeLayout.setEnabled(topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
        }
    });
```

Edit: Encountered an issue with this on android 4.3. I have updated the code to reflect the fix

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your FrameLayout inside ScrollView

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fl_webview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </ScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```